# Does the TCP connection created by requests persist when using Celery workers?

Tags: celery, django-celery, python-requests

I plan to have celery workers sending notifications to mobile devices (e.g. through GCM) and wish to avoid opening needlessly many TCP connections

I have a celery task defined like this:

```
@task()
def send_push_notification(
    requests.post(...)
)
```

Suppose this task is executed by a worker on a single machine.  Will each subprocess open only one TCP connection?  Or will a new connection be created each time the task is executed?

If I want to reuse the same TCP connection for each subprocess, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks!